# DeviceIoControl output buffer is empty

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

I am trying to pass some data from my kernel driver up to the user application.

I have defined the structure in my header file shared by my driver and application:

```
    typedef struct _CallBack
{
    HANDLE  hParId;
    HANDLE  hProId;
    BOOLEAN bCreate;
}CB_INFO, *PCB_INFO;
```

In my driver, I have a switch statement

```
case IOCTL_CODE:    
if (outputBufferLength >= sizeof(PCB_INFO))
    {
           callback->hParId = deviceExtension->hParId;
           callback->hProId = deviceExtension->hProId;
           callback->bCreate = deviceExtension->bCreate;

           Irp->IoStatus.Information = outputBufferLength;

           Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
```

I have tried debugging the code by using DbgPrint, there was nothing wrong with the if statement, as outputBufferLength is 12 and PCB_INFO is 8.

As for the DeviceIoControl code in my application:

```
    DeviceIoControl(
                driver,
                IOCTL_CODE,
                0,
                0,
                &callback,
                sizeof(callback),
                &bytesReturn,
                NULL);
```

I have checked the bytesReturn and it does not return 0, it returns a 12.

Other info: 
I am using 64-bit Windows 7.

I really have no idea what is wrong, and really would appreciate any form of help. I would be glad to provide more of my code if you need more details. Could it be something to do with me writing the driver on a 64-bit platform, or is there just something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PCB_INFO is a pointer, so sizeof(PCB_INFO) is wrong, you should be using sizeof(CB_INFO).  Also, since sizeof(callback) is 12 your application must be 32-bit.  HANDLE is only 4 bytes in 32-bit code, but is 8 bytes in 64-bit code, including your device driver, so your structures are mismatched.  Either make your application 64-bit or use a type with a constant size such as QWORD.

Comment: If the application must be 32-bit, see [Supporting 32-Bit I/O in Your 64-Bit Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you so much for your help! It finally worked! Do you want to answer this question so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I have a similar trouble but not understood how to fix my trouble
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780993/ioctl-driver-systembuffer-always-null?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, PCB_INFO is a pointer type, so `sizeof(PCB_INFO)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the buffer you're pointing to.  Use `sizeof(CB_INFO)` or `sizeof(*PCB_INFO)` instead.  The code shown in the question is actually writing past the end of the buffer, so the results are unpredictable.

Secondly, your structure includes two elements of type `HANDLE` which has a different size in 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.  In most situations Windows automatically takes care of converting ("thunking") between 32-bit and 64-bit structures, but in the case of I/O control codes this is your driver's responsibility.  This is described in the DDK article [Supporting 32-Bit I/O in Your 64-Bit Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively you can make your application 64-bit, or change the structure so that it uses only elements of constant size.